# Trigonometry and factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am searching to simplify this expression to find angle values between zero and $2\pi$:
$$4\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)-2=0$$

I have been taught to simply the trigonometric expression by factoring or by using identities but the way to proceed on this one escapes me. Otherwise I could find the answer to an equation such as the following by factoring in the following way:

$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= 2\cos^2(x)+\cos(x)-1 \\
&= (2\cos(x)-1)(\cos(x)+1) \\
\end{align*}\\
\implies \cos(x)=\frac{1}{2} \quad\text{or}\quad \cos(x)=-1
$$
So the angle $x$ would be $\pi/3$, $5\pi/3$, or $\pi$ ... in the range of $0<x<2\pi$.

I cannot factor the expression I have provided in bold by doing this process. Any recommendations?

Comment: If you make the substitution $y=sin(x)$, then it becomes 
$ 4y^2+y-2=0$. It's not gonna be very clean

Comment: How did you get from sines in the original equation to cosines in the next line, Bernardo?

Comment: Even though the equation does not factor nicely, you still obtain two real solutions for $\sin(x)$ in the range $[-1,1]$ so there will be four solutions for $x$ in $[0,2\pi]$. It's just that you will have to use the arcsine function to find them. Now if that had been $4\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)-3=0\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

You should introduce the substitution: $\sin{x}=t$.

Now your equation looks like this: $4t^2+t-2=0$.

You can solve it as a regular quadratic equation.

$$t_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{33}}{8}$$

Then you ought to revert the substitution.

$$t_1=\sin{x_1}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{33}}{8}\Rightarrow x_1=\arcsin{\frac{-1-\sqrt{33}}{8}}$$
$$t_2=\sin{x_2}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{33}}{8}\Rightarrow x_2=\arcsin{\frac{-1+\sqrt{33}}{8}}$$

Since you require $x\in(0, 2\pi)$ and $x_1$ is negative, you can add a period to the solution and get:

$$x_1=2\pi + \arcsin{\frac{-1-\sqrt{33}}{8}}$$
$$x_2=\arcsin{\frac{-1+\sqrt{33}}{8}}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's just
$$4\sin^2x+\sin x-2=4\left(\sin x-\frac{-1-\sqrt{33}}{8}\right)\left(\sin x-\frac{-1+\sqrt{33}}{8}\right)$$